# Using FormValidation with a partially pre-filled form, how can add checks to valid fields?

Tags: jquery, forms, formvalidation.io

I have certain fields (like "firstName") which I can pre-fill. However, I would like to check these against FormValidation and visually show the users which fields are complete. When I pre-fill the field, however, no visual feedback is given until I press Submit. I tried "checkValidation" but this does not do the trick.

`$('#firstName')[0].checkValidity();`

`<input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" value="@ViewBag.FirstName" />`

I tried delaying filling the value until after the validation script, but this does not help either.

Comment: Validation is usually triggered by events such as keyup, blur, and submit.  Since the field is filled in already, you do not have the first two events and nothing happens until you click submit.  You could probably write a handler that programmatically triggers validation when the page is loaded, assuming the developer provides a method for programmatically triggering validation.

Comment: See:  http://formvalidation.io/examples/field-value-changed-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

You can manually trigger the formValidation feedback. See this example:

```
        $('#myUpgradeForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'firstName');
```

More Info:
http://formvalidation.io/examples/